# Would a flying superhuman leave a contrail behind?

Tags: science-based, physics, super-powers, clouds

I'm writing a speculative fiction story that includes superhumans, and I'm trying to get some of the specifics nailed down. Several of my superhumans have the typical powers of flight, usually able to break the sound barrier but not exceeding Mach 5. They'll fly everywhere from ground level to about 10 km above the ground.

I'm trying to determine if they'll leave a contrail behind them as they fly through the atmosphere. From my preliminary research on contrails (thank you, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrail)) I've learned that these are produced by either the condensation of warm CO<sub>2</sub> and H<sub>2</sub>O **or** by pressure changes. My superhumans don't use combustion to fly, so it seems like the only way contrails could form would be via pressure differentials created by flying at supersonic speeds.

**Would a superhuman flying through the air leave a contrail behind?** If so, would it be permanent or under what conditions (speed, altitude) would this occur?

Edit: This question is specifically about the movement of a (human) body through the atmosphere under the defined circumstances, not *how* such movement might occur or the ramifications of such movement on clothes etc.

**Bounty edit:** I'm offering a bounty because the current answers, while helpful, don't provide actual estimates for the environmental conditions and velocities required to create a contrail. I'm aware that it's *possible* to create a contrail by passing a body through air fast enough under the right conditions, but my question is whether a Mach 5 superhuman would do so near ground level and in the mid-troposphere.

**Bounty award** I’m giving the bounty to Slipoch, but not the green check mark. If somebody’s able to answer the question and provide estimates of the speeds and environmental conditions required, I’ll contribute a larger bounty for an exemplary answer.

Answer (score 15):

Contrails are not produced by exhaust (aided in creation but not created by), as mentioned in my comment on the answer below. This is a pretty common misconception, which led to the rise of the idea of chemtrails.

You can see contrails on WW1 aeroplanes, and other non-jet propulsion based aircraft (such as twin & quad prop planes). How would that work if you assume a jet engine produces them? Jet engine exhaust does have a high water content, so it would aid the formation of contrails in the lower pressure area left behind.

They are actually produced by the condensation of air containing water in the lower pressure behind the wing tips, this is why even 4 jet engine planes often only leave 2 trails, it is all dependant on pressure and humidity at the altitude as well as any excess water vapour from the jet engine.

So yes, as long as the shape of the object moving fast enough is the right shape to create low enough pressure in it's wake and the water content of the surrounding air is high enough, then it can create a contrail.

Comment: good answer, though anything moving through the atmosphere inherently creates pressure differentials in its wake. Except maybe for something like tear drop shaped.

Comment: Hi Slipoch, thanks for the answer! Do you have any idea what ballpark those numbers (mostly speed) are in? I’m aware that if things move fast through the atmosphere, they’ll have contrails. I’m trying to figure out if Mach 1 and a human shape will leave behind a contrail.

Comment: What would be the right shape? Would it help if the superhuman were flying in a T-pose (assuming not wings)? With both arms stretched forward? The Superman (1 arm forward like he's punching the air)? Head first with arms at their sides?

Comment: I have one particular bone to pick with this answer, that being that you *do* see 4 contrails form behind a 4 engine aircraft.

Comment: Hi Dubukay, sorry man, it would depend on too many factors such as the water content at that altitude, air pressure, speed and shape of the body etc.

Comment: Hi Separatrix,You do not always see 4 trails behind a 4 jet engine plane, sometimes you will see two, occasionally I have seen one.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to go as fast as Mach 5 and at high altitude. Contrails, or vapour trails can be produced at low altitude and relatively slow speeds: the following photo shows trails coming from the propeller tips of an aircraft on the ground:
[image]

And here produced by a race car:

[image]

And before it's pointed out these are caused by a lift (or downforce) generating surface, here's a photo of a contrail produced by a bullet:

[image]

If you have the right conditions, namely a decent level of humidity, something going fast enough generating turbulence behind it, such as a flying human, could generate contrail.

Answer (score 3):

[Meteor contrails](https://www.nature.com/news/russian-meteor-largest-in-a-century-1.12438) seem to be a thing.  I haven't been able to find any data on the velocities involved, but I would assume they are high.

Comment: Meteors are actively burning in the atmosphere

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. They would not leave them in general. Only when they go fast and do sharp turns in humid air, need to note this trails will be small compared to trails of engines.

Comment: Maybe their flying superpower comes with supersweating, so they make the air around them very humid by just flying through it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think humans can leave aerodynamic contrails because nothing on the human body resembles the wings of an airplane, which are designed to create pressure differentials.  Our heads are rounded, our limbs are like cylinders, and even our Air Jordans lack large planar surfaces.  If a flying superhuman were to extend sword blades in his arms, like Deadpool, then perhaps contrails would form.

Comment: You know what might create a pressure differential?  A large non-aerodynamic solid object moving through air faster than the speed of sound - you'll get high-pressure air bleeding off the front, and a partial vacuum directly behind since there will be no tapering to help reintegrate the vortices in the wake.